# UICollectionView Horizontal Auto Scrolling cells

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uicollectionview

I have 5 collection view cells that I would like to scroll automatically, all the codes I've tried doesn't seem to work for my project. What am I doing wrong?

```
var scrollingTimer = Timer()

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return DataServices.instance.getClView().count
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    if let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "InsideCollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as? InsideCollectionViewCell{

    let promo = DataServices.instance.getClView()[indexPath.row]


        cell.updateViews(clView: promo)
        return cell
    }

     var rowIndex = indexPath.row

    let numberOfRecords: Int = DataServices.instance.getClView().count - 1
    if (rowIndex < numberOfRecords){
        rowIndex = (rowIndex + 1)
    }else{
        rowIndex = 0
    }

    scrollingTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 2.0, target: self, selector: #selector(MainTableViewCell.startTimer(theTimer:)), userInfo: rowIndex, repeats: true)

    return InsideCollectionViewCell()
}

@objc func startTimer(theTimer:Timer) {

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0, delay: 0, options: .curveEaseIn, animations: {

        self.clCollectionView.scrollToItem(at: IndexPath(row: theTimer.userInfo! as! Int, section: 0), at: .centeredHorizontally, animated: false)

    }, completion: nil)

}
```

Comment: Inside the block can you add `clColledtionView.layoutSubviews()`

Comment: tried it but nothing changed